# WPF Markup.XamlReader.Load cannot set DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I cannot open a .xaml file with custom namespace with Markup.XamlReader.Load method. I do like this:

```
stream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext parserContext = new System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext();
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("ex", "clr-namespace=Extensions;assembly=Extensions");

viewport = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(stream, parserContext) as Viewport3D;
```

I have the following DependencyProperty in an assembly;

```
namespace Extensions
{
    public class Ext
    {
        public static DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Ext));

        public static string GetName(DependencyObject target)
        {
            return (string)target.GetValue(NameProperty);
        }

        public static void SetName(DependencyObject target, string name)
        {
            target.SetValue(NameProperty, name);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I get a XamlParseException at XamlReader.Load method telling me this: Cannot set unknown member {clr-namespace=Extensions;assembly=Extensions}Name.

The "unkown member" in the .xaml file is set to a ModelVisual3D object like this:

All I can find about this error suggests me to do things I've alreade tried. Please help me!

Comment: Are you sure that the class that is calling `XamlReader.Load` has access to the `Extensions` assembly? Does it have the correct reference and `using` declaration included?

Comment: Yes, just to be sure  I did the simple test:

Comment: TextBox test = new TextBox();
Extensions.Ext.SetName(test, "Test");
test.Text = Extensions.Ext.GetName(test); //It sets the text to "test"

Comment: The "unkown member" in the .xaml file fell off the question it was: ex:Name="MyName"

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both class name and property name in XAML for attached properties. E.g.

```xml
<TextBox ex:Ext.Name="MyName"/>
```